# How to fix Wordpress PHP Fatal error: mysql2date()

Tags: php, wordpress, webshop

I have a website, where I get this PHP Fatal error.

```
[15-Jan-2021 15:20:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql2date() in /webshop/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php:4332
```

I have tried searching different things on google, and they all says that it is something about the Wordpress core files.
I have made a reinstall of Wordpress, as they say, and it work for 2-5 reloads, then I get the same error.

A list of plugins:

- WooCommerce
- WooCommerce Subscriptions

Hope that someone can help me out.

Comment: Disable your plugins?

Comment: Well, it's a webshop, so I can't disable these two plugins, sadly :/